Sage Binary Quadratic solve does not return all solutions
I have the equation $m = x^2 + ny^2$ where $n$ is prime and $m$ is a brilliant number. I know instances of this equation for $m,n$ values where there are two unique solutions -- i.e. solutions $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ such that both $x,y>0$ and $x_1\not=y_2$.
I would expect sage's BQF.solve_integer() would return both solutions but it only returns one. Is there any way to get the second one? Any software that would solve it and return both solutions?
For example:
q=31, p=23, m=713 

m = x^2 + 22*y^2 
Sage: (19, 4)
Unique: [(19, 4), (25, 2)]

m = x^2 + 37*y^2
Sage: (11, 4)
Unique: [(11, 4), (26, 1)]


Thank you.

Wolfram Alpha works

Maple's isolve(713=x^2+22*y^2) also works.

solve_integer gives you a solution, not all solutions. Still, SageMath is able to find all solutions using solve_diophantine:
var('x y')
print(solve_diophantine(713 == x^2 + 22*y^2))

outputs
[(-25, -2), (-19, 4), (19, 4), (25, 2), (-25, 2), (19, -4), (25, -2), (-19, -4)]

Check here. However, per documentation it is using SymPy, so you might just as well consider using that directly.
You can achieve the same also by:
var('x y')
assume(x, 'integer')
assume(y, 'integer')
print(solve(713 == x^2 + 22*y^2, x, y))

